# Question from triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

in ABC, P and Q are points on sides AB and AC respectively,  such that PQ||BC . If AP=2.4 cm, AQ=2cm , QC=3 cm and BC=6cm , find AB and PQ?

Comment: Hint: Use the properties of similar triangles

Comment: Hint 2: Don't ask questions like this

Comment: And why is that

Comment: @jaska Comments like the are not constructive and quite blunt. If you feel that a user is doing something wrong (esspecially a new user), then it is more constructive to kindly bring this to their attention and give suggestions for improvement. In doing so, it often helps to point them to helpful *help center pages* or *Meta posts*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triangle APQ and ABC are similar
APQ is scaled $\frac{AQ+QC}{AQ}=2.5$ times to form ABC. Because they are similar triangles, $AB=2.5AP$ and $BC=2.5PQ$

Since AP and BC is already known, you can easily solve for AB and PQ:

$AB=2.5•2.4cm=6cm$

$PQ=\frac{6cm}{2.5}=2.4cm$

Comment: You can obtain $2.5 \cdot 2.4$ by typing 2.5 \cdot 2.4 when you are in math mode.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig • works here so i used it, normally I'll use \cdot if • doesn't work(almost all the time)